# Boolean logic simplification

Tags: boolean, logic

I am trying to solve this but am having a hard time:
' means complement
Y = A'B' + A'BC' + (A + C')'
My attempt:
A'B' + A'BC' + A'C
A'(B' + BC' + C)
Now this is where I am lost at. Somehow parenthesized expression evaluates to 1 but am not sure how.
**EDIT: Solved now.**

Comment: I don't think you should ask about boolean logic here.

Comment: Where else should I ask it?

Comment: Not too sure, but here is what i have worked out.
A'B' + A'BC' + (A + C’)’ = A’B’ + A’BC’ +A’C = A’(B’+C +BC’) = A’(B’+C+B) = A’(C+1) = A'

The rule that you needed was this A+A'B = A+B

Comment: Ahhh I see. I was forgetting that when you do or with 1, it simplifies to 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always like to write a program for this sort of stuff to see if the logic reasoning will hold out:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    puts ("A B C");
    for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
                int x = !a && !b;
                int y = !a && b && !c;
                int z = !(a || !c);
                printf ("%d %d %d -> %d %d %d -> %d\n",
                    a, b, c, x, y, z, x || y || z);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
A B C
0 0 0 -> 1 0 0 -> 1
0 0 1 -> 1 0 1 -> 1
0 1 0 -> 0 1 0 -> 1
0 1 1 -> 0 0 1 -> 1
1 0 0 -> 0 0 0 -> 0
1 0 1 -> 0 0 0 -> 0
1 1 0 -> 0 0 0 -> 0
1 1 1 -> 0 0 0 -> 0
```

and you can tell that the simplified expression is just `A'`. You can also see the reason why, due to the middle section which shows the three individual terms which are `OR`-ed together to get the final result.

- When `A` is true (the final four lines), all three terms are false, so `OR`-ing those gives false as well. The first two terms `A'B'` and `A'BC'` are false because they both `AND` with the false `A'`. The final term has `A+C'` which is always true (because true `OR` anything is true), meaning that the negation of that is always false.
- Turning to the top four lines, when `A` and `B` are both false, the first term `A'B'` is true, so the other two terms don't matter (true `OR` anything `OR` anything is true).
- That leaves only the third and fourth line. On the third, `A` and `C` are both false and `C` is true, meaning that the middle term `A'BC'` is true.
- The fourth line has `A` false and `C` true so `A+C'` gives false or false -> false so the third term `(A+C')'` is true (`B` is irrelevant).

---

Doing it the CompSci way, you just have to step through it, applying rules:

```
     A'B' + A'BC' + (A+C')'
=    A'B' + A'BC' + A'C         # "De Morgan" final term       [note 1]
= A'(B'   + BC'   + C)          # extract common A'            [note 2]
= A'(B'   + B     + C)          # (B and not C) or C -> B or C [note 3]
= A'(    T        + C)          # (not B or B) -> true         [note 4]
= A'(        T       )          # true or anything -> true     [note 4]
= A'                            # X and true -> X              [note 4]
```

**Notes:**

1/ De Morgans law simply states that `a'b' -> (a+b)'` and `a'+b' -> (ab)'`.

2/ The distributive law `ax+ay -> a(x+y)`.

3/ Not sure if this law has a name but, if `c` is true, the whole expression is true. If `c` is false then it comes down to `b and true` or just `b`. That's effectively `b+c`.

4/ These go without saying though, as any good mathematician should tell you, very little *should* go without saying in formal proofs :-)